# Install Webmin on my Raspberry Pi 3 B Stops

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, web-interface

I've have tried several times to install Webmin on my Raspberry Pi 3 B with no luck. I have expanded the OS to the 32gb micro SD Card, and even changed the SD Card twice.

It will download everything correctly but it will only install up to this point:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y --force-yes -f install \
  perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime \
  libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python 

wget -O webmin.deb http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.791_all.deb

sudo dpkg -D1 -i webmin.deb 

D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: ensure_statoverrides: new, (re)loading (Reading database ... 152644 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack webmin.deb ... 
D000001: process_archive oldversionstatus=broken due to postinst failure 
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
Unpacking webmin (1.791) over (1.791) ... 
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping 
D000001: process_archive updating info directory
D000001: generating infodb hashfile
D000001: process queue pkg webmin:all queue.len 0 progress 1, try 1 
Setting up webmin (1.791) ...
D000001: deferred_configure updating conffiles
```

/var/log/dpkg.log says:

```
2016-03-26 03:21:27 startup archives install
2016-03-26 03:21:28 install webmin:all <none> 1.791
2016-03-26 03:21:28 status half-installed webmin:all 1.791
2016-03-26 03:21:28 status triggers-pending systemd:armhf 215-17+deb8u3

2016-03-26 18:24:55 upgrade webmin:all 1.791 1.791
2016-03-26 18:24:55 status half-configured webmin:all 1.791
2016-03-26 18:24:55 status unpacked webmin:all 1.791
2016-03-26 18:24:55 status half-installed webmin:all 1.791

2016-03-26 18:48:35 upgrade webmin:all 1.791 1.791
2016-03-26 18:48:35 status half-configured webmin:all 1.791
2016-03-26 18:48:35 status unpacked webmin:all 1.791
2016-03-26 18:48:35 status half-installed webmin:all 1.791
2016-03-26 18:48:35 status unpacked webmin:all 1.791
2016-03-26 18:48:35 status half-installed webmin:all 1.791
```

Comment: I take it nothing happens after that. How long did you wait? Try adding `-D1` to your `dpkg` run, and see if you get any useful output. Did you try installing from source, using the tar-archive?

Comment: Yes nothing happens after that, I waited over a day. I believe source "webmin_1.791_all.deb" Will try the "-D1" option.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg -D1 -i webmin.deb
D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: ensure_statoverrides: new, (re)loading
(Reading database ... 152644 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack webmin.deb ...
D000001: process_archive oldversionstatus=broken due to postinst failure
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping

Comment: D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
Unpacking webmin (1.791) over (1.791) ...
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
D000001: process_archive updating info directory
D000001: generating infodb hashfile
D000001: process queue pkg webmin:all queue.len 0 progress 1, try 1
Setting up webmin (1.791) ...
D000001: deferred_configure updating conffiles

Comment: I edited the question with the extra information. Is this the output you get?

Comment: Yes, that was with the -D attribute added

Comment: This seems very strange, because that would mean that the actual setting up of `webmin` has finished, but then `dpkg` hangs at updating config files. Are you sure it is hanging - or, rather: how are you sure it is hanging? What does the `/var/log/dpkg.log`say?

Comment: Looks like it is only half installing

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: 2016-03-26 18:48:35 status half-installed webmin:all 1.791

Comment: Try running `sudo -D1 -P webmin` to purge the package from your system, then try installing it again. If this doesn't work, then I'd recommend trying to install from source.